# Examples of being bounced by Salesforce Support to forums when encountering a GACK

Tags: discussion

I'm looking to provide a number of examples to Salesforce where someone has encountered a [GACK](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html) and tried to raise a support case that has subsequently been closed because they don't have access to Premier Support.

The more recent the better. I can see a lot of [questions about GACKs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gack?mixed=1), but it isn't always clear how their interactions with Salesforce support went.

**Please try and keep the responses factual.** E.g. Case Numbers, dates, and response indicating that you should take the GACK to the forums. I know full well how frustrating a GACK just before deployment to production can be, but I'd like to avoid degenerating into another ["Whale Sperm">Support rant post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/589/102) :)

*My goal is to get a positive change to the support process for GACKs where people don't have access to Premier support.*

---

Some examples I've found so far:

- [Getting a log/stack trace from an Error Id with basic support](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/120242/102)

> “I created an support case asking if they could send us the error log
>   or stack-trace for the given Error Id. I agent said that because they
>   are on the "basic" support tier he could not give me that
>   information.”

- [Netsuite -> Salesforce integration - Salesforce error](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/98745/102)

> “We tried opening a case to salesforce but the closed it because we do
>   not have a development support.”

- [An internal server error has occurred Error ID: 84564146-14190 (747219706)](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000MPa8QAG)

> “I called technical support but they don't provide standard support to
>   developer account. Please help me to solve this problem.”

- [Test.setCreatedDate fails on note record created in test context](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/117473/102)

> "I attempted to file a case with support, but since the company I work
>   for cannot afford premier support, and developer accounts have no
>   support access, my only option to try and contact salesforce was to
>   post this question onto the Salesforce Success Community forums."

---

If you do have examples of working with support on a GACK, can you also answer the following questions.

- In the situations where people found a gack, were they pointed to a Known Issue?
- In the situations where people found a gack, did the support agent take down the steps for reproduction?

---

**UPDATE**

I've sent the feedback through to the Salesforce contact to see if they can improve the process. I'd also raised this in the Dreamforce 2017 *Meet the Developers* session.

As an experiment I raised a support case from a Developer Edition org with no connection to Premier support (17719714). I intentionally didn't use the term GACK and just included the Error ID.

To their credit, support:

- reproduced the error from my steps,
- isolated the cause,
- gave me a work around, and
- gave me a bug reference (W-4500854) if I wanted to get updates in the future
- said they would raise a known issue if it impacted other customers.

So a pretty good outcome in may case. Your mileage may vary.

---

**Update 2: 2nd December 2017**

Response from Salesforce on GACK support:

> As I mentioned before, everyone, not just Premier support members, should have the ability to get limited gack (Internal Server Error) support.  By limited, I mean that we can't help customers debug the errors or their code, nor can we give them a stack trace, but we can look the error up in the internal system to give the customer some help as to what might be causing the issue.  In order to help support track down the issue, they should include the Error Id when reporting the Internal Server Error.

Comment: Here's a recent one from me - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/195045/platform-cache-system-error-random

Comment: Salesforce Support told me both these errors are related to creating ContentNote with unsupported characters. Salesforce System Error: 208410828-86802 (1615802660) and Salesforce System Error: 623811003-63707 (123133497). Usually encountered when converting Notes to ContentNote. But they didn’t pin point the specific characters that caused the issue.

Comment: I don't have support, and end up having to come here for someone else to bring the issue to support. It's a frustrating experience with a lot of extra middlemen. I wish the gack's provided useful debugging information with the id, it would at least help developers w/o support keep working.

Comment: [Heres an example](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/117473/test-setcreateddate-fails-on-note-record-created-in-test-context) from earlier this year.

Comment: I'm not sure how appropriate this thread is. It's not about Stack Exchange, and both answers just read as complaints/rants. Not certain what to do here. There don't seem to be many great alternatives to be fair.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Hmm, true. It isn't about the Salesforce Stack Exchange directly. I'm not really after the complaints/rants. More specific examples of where Support are directing those encountering GACKs to the developer forums and by indirect association here. There isn't much we can do for GACKs here, so I'm trying to provide examples to Salesforce so they can refine their processes. Ideal end result is that support will help those encountering GACKs directly and not end up here.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I don't have many other mechanisms to reach the community of Salesforce Devs and Admins who are being directly affected by this. I'll try and refine the question shortly.

Comment: I know it's a bit of a conundrum. Because there is definitely a history of closing some questions on Meta for that very reason. Maybe because those users had lower rep, or because their questions didn't really benefit the broader community. I guess correctness just has to be balanced against the greater good.

Comment: my experience is [documented here](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2084/why-doesnt-salesforce-thank-you-if-you-discover-a-reproducible-internal-salesfo)

Comment: Please don't close this question. I believe what @DanielBallinger is attempting to do can benefit everyone. Maybe ignore it for a week or two if you have to close it :) - I have found however, that if the case is closed by support, posting on the partner community will typically get it looked at and reopened....Its a drawn out way to get things done for sure

Answer (score 10):

Encountered a GACK on code that was working fine in all of my development orgs, but blew up when it was in a managed package installed on a 3rd party org.

I opened the case two weeks ago and even went through the effort of setting up two test orgs for support to show them the expected result and the GACK result. The steps for replication were clearly laid out in the description for the ticket.

I am not sure if support even bothered to log in and see the error. I was told to turn to the forums for support. Waited a day or so for the manual escalation button to appear, then I escalated the case. Promptly received a phone call that they saw the escalation and would be active in the case.

For the next week, I was getting daily comments on the case that they were reaching out to additional support teams for assistance. At the end of the week, they said they were unable to obtain support and resent the EXACT SAME form letter prompting me to turn to the forums.

I escalated the case again asking for immediate transfer to R&D. They responded that I would receive a phone call the next day, but they never called.

I closed the case yesterday out of frustration. Thanks for nothing, Salesforce.

Comment: Can you share the support case # please. This is exactly the type of feedback I want to provide.

Comment: Partner support case #17631498.

Answer (score 7):

I don't submit bugs anymore due to this, I wait for them to be resolved and in the meantime find workarounds.

I did however have an instance where, in a packaging org, I was unable to delete a field (field was not part of the packageyet) and when doing so it produced a GACK:

> Error ID: 1800041251-29917 (-596761184)

The Tier 1 rep said there was no way for SF to access a GACK Log. They wanted me to reproduce the scenario which I was unwilling to do as it would have put the managed application at risk if the field could not be deleted.

I asked repeatedly to be escalated or to be provide with the GACK log so I could determine what was going on to no avail and they closed the case.

**Case# 16711375**

Ultimately I was able to find that by modifying the Child Relationship name on the field before deletion the field was able to be deleted. I was able to reproduce the error several times after that but the actual cause remains unknown.

I hope you get somewhere with this. As it stands ISV's end up providing free salesforce support to SF customers due to Process builder causing all sorts of problems and with the inability to report bugs it affects the quality of their product and the code written by others (workarounds).

I believe that anyone with a **Platform II / Advanced Dev** credential should have a way to report bugs that will not get immediately shut down regardless of their Premier Support status.

While this is not an exact scenario you were asking for it is one where they say they cannot access any logs for GACKs and refuse to escalate because one does not have Premier support.

Comment: _Tier 1 rep said there was no way for SF to access a GACK Log_ ... to be fair, the Tier 1 support agent may not have had permissions to the system to view the gack details. It may just be phrasing of their capabilities rather than being brushed off.

Comment: @MarkPond - Agreed,  I just simplified it and said tier one said no way to access, but they tier 1 said they are relaying what tier 2 told them when I asked them to bump to tier 2/3......

Comment: The platform II / advanced dev creds is a good idea; or sfdc MVP or 10000+ SFSE pts, etc.

Answer (score 6):

[Ghost processes / batch processes (NA34 and NA39)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/165817/ghost-processes-batch-processes-na34-and-na39)

Case# 16110681

There was an issue a while back where SF Hammer tests caused callouts to make it outside of salesforce.

I reported the case as a Bug and it was closed because the Tier 1 wanted me to reproduce. When I explained that it was impossible to reproduce because it was something on the SF side it was closed and pointed to Developer Forums.

**Important** While not a GACK, this led to SF finding out about a week later they had an issue during Hammer testing putting out an Alert to inform that during the specific timeframe callouts made it to the outside world.

This cost our customers a significant amount real money. I was added to the List of people grouped with the issue after they found out they had it.

> Bottom line, if they had not closed the case they **may** have realized there was an issue sooner